# Where is the source of Google design guidelines | Material Design

Tags: material-design

I have learned the Google design guidelines.

I have a good look at http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html.

In the github source of web-starter-kit.
But, Will there somewhere source of http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html?

Answer (score 0):

Polymer is a great library for implementing Google Material Design into your app: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/.

Also, if your are build in Angular.JS the guys at Google have created their own NPM module called Angular Material: https://material.angularjs.org. It has a number of installation methods available.

There is also another library that has incorporated Google Material Design with Bootstrap: Just search for "Bootstrap Material Design" or go [here](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design). This wonderful library is made by [FezVrasta](https://github.com/FezVrasta).

Comment: He's asking for the Java source, not a web library.

Answer (score 0):

Material Design is great thing brought by Google. Here are some of the frameworks that can be really useful to you.

1. [Materialize](http://materializecss.com): It's a great thing to start off with. Just CSS, no JavaScript.
2. [Material UI](http://material-ui.com): This is the library that I always use in my projects, but the problem that you may face is that this library is dependent on [react.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/).
3. [Leaf BETA](http://getleaf.com/): Still in beta, it has extensive list of components such as buttons, cards, sliders, menu, tabs etc. It includes icons by Icomoon, instead of the original Material design icons.
4. [Polymer Paper Elements](http://polymer-project.org): Polymer has so many things. Nearly all. It is brought by Google so you may not have any problems using that.
5. [MUI CSS Framework](https://www.muicss.com/): This is library that I use for man small projects just because it is the only library that I found having best documentation.
6. [AngularJS Material Design](http://material.angularjs.org): This is the framework that you might know. Still a lots of bugs around there.
7. [Bootstrap Material Design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/): Last but not the least, this will be extremely helpful to you if you prefer bootstrap for web designing.

As the things are changing, there might be some other framework very soon to compete with these all.